# Cutting irregular shape on image

Tags: javascript, drawing, shapes, html5-canvas

I am trying to cut an image into a particular shape using the canvas clip() method.

I have followed the following steps to do so:

1. Draw a rectangle.
2. Draw semi circles on each side. The right and bottom semi circles protrude outwards and the left and top semi circles are inwards.

The code snippet is provided below:

```
var canvasNode = this.hasNode();
var ctx = canvasNode && canvasNode.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 512, 384);
};

image.src = "images/image.png";
var startX = 200;
var startY = 0;

var rectWidth = 150;
var rectHeight = 150;
var radius = 30;

//Main Rect
ctx.rect(startX, startY, rectWidth, rectHeight);

//Right arc
ctx.moveTo(startX+=rectWidth, startY+=(rectHeight/2));
ctx.arc(startX, startY, radius, 3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, false);

//Left arc
ctx.moveTo(startX-=(rectWidth / 2), startY+=(rectHeight / 2));
ctx.arc(startX, startY, radius, 0, Math.PI, true);

ctx.moveTo(startX-=(rectWidth / 2), startY-=(rectWidth / 2));
ctx.arc(startX, startY, radius, 3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, false);

ctx.clip();
```

The image that I am using is of size 800 x 600 (png). Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, why are you using `clip`? You are currently just drawing semicircles, which works without `clip`.

Secondly, you are creating paths and clipping, but you never stroke the path. As a result, you won't see anything on the screen.

If you just stroke instead of clip, it works partially for me: http://jsfiddle.net/r6yAN/. You did not include the top semicircle though.

**Edit:** It seems like you're not using the best way of clipping. You draw a rectangle, but this also includes a line in the semicircle. You'd be better off if you draw each line/arc yourself like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CH6qB/6/.

The main idea is to move from point to point as in this image:

[image]

So first start at `(startX, startY)`, then a line to `(startX + lineWidth, startY)`, then an arc at `(startX + rectWidth / 2, startY)` from `pi` to `0` (counterclockwise), etc.

If you want to stroke the path as well after having drawn the image, it is a good idea to unclip again. Otherwise, the stroke will not be of great quality.

```
var canvasNode = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = canvasNode && canvasNode.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    // draw the image, region has been clipped
    ctx.drawImage(image, startX, startY);

    // restore so that a stroke is not affected by clip
    // (restore removes the clipping because we saved the path without clip below)
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.stroke();
};

image.src = "http://www.lorempixum.com/200/200/";

var startX = 200;
var startY = 0;

var rectWidth = 150;
var rectHeight = 150;
var radius = 30;

var lineWidth  = rectWidth  / 2 - radius;
var lineHeight = rectHeight / 2 - radius;

// typing pi is easier than Math.PI each time
var pi = Math.PI;

ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);

ctx.lineTo(startX + lineWidth, startY);
ctx.arc(startX + rectWidth / 2, startY,
        radius,
        pi, 0, true);
ctx.lineTo(startX + rectWidth, startY);

ctx.lineTo(startX + rectWidth, startY + lineHeight);
ctx.arc(startX + rectWidth, startY + rectHeight / 2,
        radius,
        -pi / 2, pi / 2, false);
ctx.lineTo(startX + rectWidth, startY + rectHeight);

ctx.lineTo(startX + rectWidth - lineWidth, startY + rectHeight);
ctx.arc(startX + rectWidth / 2, startY + rectHeight,
        radius,
        0, pi, false);
ctx.lineTo(startX, startY + rectHeight);

ctx.lineTo(startX, startY + rectHeight - lineHeight);
ctx.arc(startX, startY + rectHeight / 2,
        radius,
        pi/2, pi*3/2, true);
ctx.lineTo(startX, startY);

ctx.save(); // Save the current state without clip

ctx.clip();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to cut the image in a particular shape. Sorry missed the top arc code, here is the modified snippet with the top arc drawn http://jsfiddle.net/CH6qB/ I was not sure how to include an image in jsfiddle :( so the image is not present. When I apply clip, the left arc and the top arc do not get cut out of the image. This path that I am trying to cut is part of a jigsaw puzzle. I am generating a pattern so that I can replicate them.

Comment: @quad_damage: I see what you mean. I did not notice the image you were drawing... Sorry for that.

Comment: @quad_damage: Could you please vote/accept this answer in that case?