# cut a triangle from an image using canvas (like iOS background with open folder)

Tags: jquery, image, canvas

I want to recreate the iOS folders effect.
Everything works fine, but I need to find a better way to cut a triangle from the upper image and leave the triangle on the lower image.

Here's an image to show what I mean

[image]

I am currently using .png arrows that overlay the image, but I really want it to be 100% realistic.

You can see the folder effect I am currently usig here:
http://webkit-os.pixelass.com/iframe

(webkit browsers only... best in Safari Mac OS X  or mobile Safari)

I found this page:
[Cutting irregular shape on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677199/cutting-irregular-shape-on-image)

And played around with this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CH6qB/6/

But all I managed to achieve was this.
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/rWbNu/

I guess I really don't understand how drawing a canvas works and I couldn't find anything that describes it the way I need it.
So if anybody can help me it would be great.
I am also fine with a link to a good tutorial or canvas explanation page.
Oh.. and I don't really know about javascript.
I can do pretty wicked stuff in jQuery though, so I would appreciate a somewhat jQuery kind of way to do this.

I'd be happy for any kind of help.
Perfect would be to create a simple fiddle how it would work.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

For anybody interested in this. I added an example with dynamic positions. it also shows how this approach respects changing the wallpaper (cookie support in this example). The Newsstand-Folder has a different Background than the App-Folders. Everything happens automatically.

everything is done by CSS transition and animation. jQuery is only used to change the properties and classes. I'm still not perfectly happy but the rest is only finetuning.

Here's a Demo for Webkit browsers: http://webkit-os.pixelass.com/foldertest/

If anybody cares about this please tell me and I will upload the Demo as a .ZIP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really get the question, but are the arrows you are referring to the little pseudo element pointers when you open something on an iPhone?

If so, I whipped up a really fast fiddle on how they are done : http://jsfiddle.net/JXgk9/1/

If not, try explaining a little better exactly what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes I mean that exact arrow. but I need it to be cut from the upper image instead of overlaying it

Comment: I am basically doing something similar to your example, but I'm not happy with it. I posted a link to the project (in case you did not see it). You can see the folder effect here: http://webkit-os.pixelass.com/iframe (webkit browsers only... best in Safari Mac OS X or mobile Safari)

Comment: Can't really help you with that, guess you are stuck with canvas clipping or xor composites. There is a css mask composite, but I believe only webkit supports it, and I don't really know how to use it. Most iPhone demos, and just about every other site out there with arrows like that, uses the before/after pseudo elements or classes with borders, and I can't really find any good reasons at all to do it the way you want to, by pointing it inwards and thus removing a piece of an element instead of just overlaying it, but that's up to you, but canvas will add some overhead just for a small arrow.

Comment: There are quite a few reasons, why to do it the way I want. Most importantly to get the original effect. This only has to work on webkit browsers, well actually only on iOS. I was thinking about using a css mask (I am doing that for the TabBar in the Music app), but I want to make sure I'm using the perfect solution for the wallpaper. Using a css mask for this would need a workaround and I want to keep those as rare as possible.

Comment: A css solution would be a lot faster than canvas, and add very litle overhead, and if it only has to work in iOS I would probably have preferred the css soulution over canvas any day, even with the workarounds and masks etc. If only there where a XOR thingy in CSS, like there is in canvas, with cross browser support, this would be amazingly simple to accomplish by just placing a before/after arrow inside the element and setting a XOR composite to remove both the arrow and a piece of the underlying element, but the closest thing to that existing today would have to be the webkit masks. GoodLuck

Comment: .. hm.. I just had an idea.. it could probably work in CSS without a  png mask. The problem with a mask is, that box-shadows will not display at all if outset and clipped if inset. But maybe by half clipping and rotated box with an opposite rotated box inside, with the image as background and the correct offset will work. I'd still have to overlay the other image, but it would be dynamic for any given background and display the exact part of the image/pattern below. I'll just give it a try.

Comment: That's one way to do it, and possible. I built an entire site a few years back with rotated boxes inside other boxes with overflow hidden to make rectangles with borders. Had to use javascript to calculate diagonals to get right size and position, but worked just fine and gave the option to make the entire site with some special effects. It's currently down being upgraded to css tranforms, but a little copy and paste, and at least the header and contact form is in this fiddle, but looks terrible without shadows and overlays (too much to add to fiddle) - {link](http://jsfiddle.net/JvUW4/1364/)

Comment: That site is built with a colorwheel in the footer, and the footer has the opposite shape of the header and closes like a hatch, and everything changes color dynamicly to any color as everything is built with actual html elements, box shadow works, and it resizes to the browser window. These days most browsers supports skewing, but back then some creative javascript rotation was the way to go. Just to show that rotating an element, and sticking it halfway inside another element with no overflow gives a lot of flexibility, if it's usable for your application.

Comment: I guess I'll try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/k54rs/ (webkit only)  I just made this fiddle. I just need to get the Background positions of the arrow-inside correct. But the show hide effect should be pretty close to iOS.

Comment: sadly it won't correctly/smoothly work on an iPhone.  But I guess it's a starting point. I added a more advanced example in my first post. So I need to find a way to get the same effect but smoother animations /Timieout-settings...

Comment: Not sure if it will help at all, but you could try animating it with jQuery instead, using the $.fn.step method. Created a quick fiddle to show how it's done, and using this method you can animate anything, in any direction, from / to any number : http://jsfiddle.net/XnA2f/1/

Comment: Hm. I actually didn't know about .step(). I will definitely Play around with it. So far I only know that -webkit-transform translate...(x) with -webkit-Transition or Delay is a Lot smoother than using .animate() or setTimeout

Comment: Thinking about my last comment... -webkit-animations are really smooth too, so I'll play around with those a little. I can make the entire animation in CSS... I already made a new version without timeout and animate() and it's a lot faster with CSS delay and transition

Comment: Ahh, ok, I actually thought you already used css animations, and just suggested the step method as the only option I could think of. If so, I agree that css animations are a lot smoother and faster than jQuery, and is probably the better choice.

Comment: here's an example with -webkit-animations and keyframes. it actually works pretty nice . There is some flickering on the iphone.. but I only tested it in the jfiddle shell. So it either has to do with that, or with animating opacity by css (I remember having had problems before). This still needs some tuning, but anyways.. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/zTwyt/29/